# In Kotlin, what is the difference between assignment and assignment expression?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this code:

```
  fun bind(item: ReturnRequestRowVO) {
    returnRequestInfoDate?.text = item.dateReturnPurchaseText?.let {
      HtmlCompat.fromHtml(it, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    }
    setupReturnRequestBtn(item)
  }
```

And Android Studio recommends:

[image: Code fragment]

If I apply the change:

```
  fun bind(item: ReturnRequestRowVO) {
    item.dateReturnPurchaseText?.let {
      HtmlCompat.fromHtml(it, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
    }.also { returnRequestInfoDate?.text = it }
    setupReturnRequestBtn(item)
  }
```

What is the difference between assignment and assignment expression?

Comment: The assignment expression will also return the assigned value, because `also` is returning its input. There is no other difference. Because you are not using the returned value for anything here, I would prefer the normal assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An assignment is a statement that sets a value to something, whereas an expression is a statement that returns something.

```
// Assignment: nothing returns from the = operator.
val a = 1 

// Expression: it returns 8 (although you're not storing it anywhere).
6 + 2
```

You can put each of these statements in a method and:

```
fun assignment() {
  val a = 2
}

fun assignmentExpression(): Int = 6 + 2
```

The first method's return type is `Unit`, since the `=` operator doesn't return  anything (e. i., it's not an expression), whereas the second one is `Int`, because the `+` operator returns a number of type `Int` (which makes it an expression).

I see eye to eye with @marstran up there. The first version (assignment) is better, since you only need to assign a value, it is more straightforward to me.

`also()` returns the object over which it is called, which is something you actually don't need at all in this example (you're not keeping the result of `also`, you're ignoring it's return value). However, because Kotlin is much more functional-friendly (hence much more [expression-oriented](https://thomasbandt.com/what-is-functional-programming)), the compiler is suggesting you to use expressions over assingments because it gives you more flexibility, since you can concatenate calls over expressions, but not over assignments. That's why it's moving the assignment to the end of the sentence.

Also, if you think of Git, using something that you can concatenate calls to instead of having to modify it, saves line changes in code reviews, should anyone have to do something with the value returned by `also()`.

So actually, whichever option you choose depends on the approach that you're using when coding and what you think it might be more useful to your project.

I don't know about performance in this case, but I don't think it should matter too much.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, as in many other languages, there is a distinction between an assignment and an expression. Let's break down the difference:

1. **Assignment**:

   - It's an operation that gives a value to a variable.
   - In Kotlin, assignment uses the `=` operator.
   - For instance: `val x = 10` or `var y: Int; y = 20`.
   - Assignments in Kotlin do not evaluate to a value. Therefore, you can't do things like `val z = (y = x)`, because `(y = x)` doesn't produce a value.
2. **Assignment Expressions**:

   - Some languages allow assignments to be expressions, which means they produce a value when evaluated. This is common in C, C++, and Java, among others.
   - In those languages, you might see code like `while((x = getNext()) != null) { ... }`, where the assignment `(x = getNext())` has a value, which is the value assigned to `x`.
   - However, Kotlin deliberately avoids making assignments expressions. This decision was made to avoid potential errors and to make the code clearer.
   - In Kotlin, if you want to assign a value to a variable and use it in a single expression, you typically use the `also` extension function, or use a block:

     ```kotlin
     val x = getNext().also { y = it }
     ```

     Or:

     ```kotlin
     val x = run {
        y = getNext()
        y
     }
     ```

In summary, the main distinction in Kotlin is that assignments (`=`) don't produce values, which means they aren't usable in contexts that expect a value (like the right-hand side of another assignment). This makes certain types of mistakes less common and promotes clearer code.